# Removing plastic aerator

Tags: bathroom, faucet, tap

I want to remove an old plastic aerator from my bathroom tap. I have tried with some universal aerator keys but my aerator doesn’t have any grooves to fit those keys. I’ve also tried to unscrew it (right to left) with pliers. It rotates with a squeaky noise but doesn’t seem to unscrew.

What am I doing wrong and how do I remove it?

[image: faucet aerator]